# How can I find a proper form for M

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$ M  =$ ${z+2}\over{z+1}$

$z=x+yi$

$x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

I tried everything but i could not do it.(include multiplying with conjugate)

How can I write a $ M$ in $a+bi$ form ?

$$M =\frac{((x+2)+iy)((x+1)-iy)}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$

$$M= \frac{x^2 +3x+2+y^2-iy}{(x+1)^2 + y^2}$$

$$a= \frac{x^2+3x+2+y^2}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$

$$b= \frac{-y}{(x+1)^2+y^2} $$

This is the process I've made

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing what exactly you have tried. Can you write it, please? Maybe it's only one step away from success ...

Comment: $Matti P. Can you check it right know ? Thanks

Comment: Yeah it looks good to me. $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Why did you think that you, quote, "could not to it"?

Comment: @Matti P. I thought I need to find something more simple at the end. It just seemed too complicated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your process and your answer are completely correct. Well done!

Comment: Thank you for checking it out